# 'is in list' for Image in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am using the MCD12Q1.006 MODIS Land Cover Type Yearly Global 500m dataset. I want to mask out non-forest types. I am using `LC_Type1` and keeping only the pixels with values 1-6. I am currently doing it this way:

```
var maskForest = function(image){
  var forestMask = image.gte(1).and(image.lte(6))
  return image.updateMask(forestMask)
}
var forest = landCover.select('LC_Type1').map(maskForest)
```

But since I may also want pixels with value 10 (for example) I wonder if there is a method like `series.isin([1,2,3,4,5,6])` in pandas, python, instead of using a lot of `and`, `or`.

Comment: I've used it with ee.Filter.isin() but not with a mask.  The only way I can think of would be to have a series of masks that then update in series the returned image.

Comment: Could ee.Filter work in this case if I  give up using mask? I thought filter will filter out images/features that don't match the conditions in imageCollection/FeatureCollection. Could it also work for filtering out pixels in an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that something like `.isin()` exists. `ee.Filter.isin()` won't do what you would like to do since as you said it only works on Image Collections.

However a not too complicated workaround is posible with `.eq()` and `.reduce()`.

```
// Random image with range from 0-10
var test = ee.Image.random().multiply(10).floor()
// Making boolean mask with 1-6 as True
var isin = test.eq([1,2,3,4,5,6]).reduce('sum')

Map.addLayer(test)
Map.addLayer(isin)
```

As a short disclaimer: I do not know how computationally efficient this is. My gut instinct is telling me that the greater than/less than approach would be faster, but I haven't tested it. So I do agree that it would be handy to have a dedicated `.isin()` solution (It shouldn't be too hard to implement for the Earth Engine devs).

Comment: This will work, and they're roughly the same cost.